# Java Array.Length is not Correct

Tags: java, eclipse

I am just starting a war card game. I made a deck and then needed to have it reshuffled. Anyways, I am going to need the .length to be correct later one. So when I used the length, it got 160 as an answer when it should be 52 as I counted. Here is the code.

```
import java.util.List;

public class wargame {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        funtionsforwargame funtionsforwargame=new funtionsforwargame();
        funtionsforwargame.instructions();
        List<String> randomized_deck=funtionsforwargame.get_deck();
        String[] deck_convert = randomized_deck.toArray(new String[0]);
        String deck=java.util.Arrays.toString(deck_convert);
        System.out.println(deck);
        System.out.println(deck.length());

    }

}
```

Also, the get_deck method creates a deck, as an array, and then converts to a list string and returns it because it needs to be shuffled. So I then take that returned list and convert it back to an array and then also make sure it gives me the deck and not some thing like ghty@67843. So if anyone knows why it is giving me 160 and not 52, that would be helpful. Here is the get_deck method in case you do not believe me that there is 52 in the list/array.

```
public class funtionsforwargame {
    public void instructions(){
        System.out.println("Welcome to War!");
        System.out.println("The object of the game is to collect all cards from the other person.");
        System.out.println("Basically, all you do is watch and press any key to go to the next round.");
        System.out.println("Good luck!!!");
    }
    public List<String> get_deck(){
        String new_deck[]={"A","A","A","A","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","4","4","4","4","5","5","5","5","6","6","6","6","7","7","7","7","8","8","8","8","9","9","9","9","10","10","10","10","J","J","J","J","Q","Q","Q","Q","K","K","K","K"};
        List<String> list_convert = Arrays.asList(new_deck);
        Collections.shuffle(list_convert);
        return list_convert;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see you getting the `length` property of any array, just you calling `length()` on a string representation of the array which contains other characters as well, e.g. commas and spaces, hence from 52 1 or 2 character elements you get a 160 character string (something like `[A, A, 2, 10, ...]` which is 48 single chars + 4 double chars + 51 times `, ` + `[` + `]` = 48 + 4*2 + 51*2 + 1 + 1 = 160 characters)

Comment: Please follow the Java naming conventions (case, spelling) as that would make your code possible to read. It's hard to distinguish the misspelled `funtionsforwargame` class from the misspelled `funtionsforwargame` variable, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you aware that:

```
int[] x = {1,2,3};
```

and

```
String y = Arrays.toString(x);
```

are TOTALLY different things?

when you do

```
System.out.println(deck);
System.out.println(deck.length());
```

length is counting the commas, spaces and [ ], why would those be the same as the 52 cards you have in the **randomized_deck**

you dont ned to use arrays at all, in yyour case a list is more than ok...

just do

```
List<String> randomized_deck = funtionsforwargame.get_deck();

System.out.println(randomized_deck);
```

and to split you can use `List#subList(....);`

Comment: I know one is an array and the other is a list. I had to convert in order to shuffle them. Any answer with how to get 52 would be helpful. I still don't know how to not get the commas, spaces, and [].

Comment: I need to be able to split the randomized deck later and then access each element in the list later. That means length has to be correct.

Comment: I still can't get the length of randomized_deck because it is a List<String>.

Comment: Ok that works, I will just work with list instead of an array for the rest of the program.

Comment: Yes.. list are almost always much better than arrays!!!... you are welcome!!! Thanks for the accepted answer!!!!

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
String deck=java.util.Arrays.toString(deck_convert);
```

The number `52` becomes `160` because the **Card 10** is `2` *digits*.

You should print the `String[] deck_convert` and not use `Arrays.toString(deck_convert)`.

```
public class wargame {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        funtionsforwargame funtionsforwargame = new funtionsforwargame();
        funtionsforwargame.instructions();
        List<String> randomized_deck = funtionsforwargame.get_deck();
        String[] deck_convert = randomized_deck.toArray(new String[0]);
        for(String card : deck_convert)
            System.out.print(card + ",");
        System.out.println(deck_convert.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the true and you can check it in the place:

```
public class wargame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        funtionsforwargame funtionsforwargame = new funtionsforwargame();
        funtionsforwargame.instructions();
        List<String> randomized_deck = funtionsforwargame.get_deck();
        String[] deck_convert = randomized_deck.toArray(new String[0]);
        String deck = java.util.Arrays.toString(deck_convert);
        System.out.println(deck_convert.length);
        System.out.println(deck);
        System.out.println(deck.length());

    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
52
[10, 2, 8, 3, A, 7, 2, 6, 8, 6, 4, K, 3, 9, 10, 3, 5, J, Q, 7, 5, 8, K, J, J, 3, A, 7, 7, 9, 2, 6, K, 4, Q, 9, A, Q, 10, A, 9, 5, K, Q, 5, 6, 8, 10, J, 4, 4, 2]
160
```

In the first case `length` gives you the quantities of elements of the array. In another you will have the real length of the already converted string.
We can easy check it by:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    funtionsforwargame funtionsforwargame = new funtionsforwargame();
    funtionsforwargame.instructions();
    List<String> randomized_deck = funtionsforwargame.get_deck();
    String[] deck_convert = randomized_deck.toArray(new String[0]);
    String deck = java.util.Arrays.toString(deck_convert);
    System.out.println(deck_convert.length);
    System.out.println(deck);
    System.out.println(deck.charAt(4));  // here we take one symbol
    System.out.println(deck.length());

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
52
[A, 7, 2, A, 2, 2, 5, A, 3, 8, 6, Q, 10, 4, K, 4, J, 3, 5, 7, 8, Q, 7, 5, 10, K, 10, 4, 9, 6, Q, 8, K, 7, 6, 9, J, J, 10, K, 5, 2, 8, 6, J, Q, 3, 4, 9, A, 3, 9]
7
160
```

As we can see the command `System.out.println(deck.charAt(4));` give us `**7**`.

Comment: So then in order to access each element later on, I would have to be accessing from the deck but like for the first element it would be the first instead of 0th element because of the [?

Comment: Yes, I just improve the example